# run code in background every 10 seconds in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to run my code in background every 10 seconds.

I use [android_alarm_manager_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) package to do this, but the code only runs one time.

```
void printHello() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
  print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId} function='$printHello'");
}


void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();

  runApp(MyApp());

  final int helloAlarmID = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), helloAlarmID, printHello);
  
}
```

output:

```
I/AlarmService(20174): AlarmService started!
W/AlarmService(20174): Attempted to start a duplicate background isolate. Returning...
I/flutter (20174): [2022-03-06 23:07:04.551284] Hello, world! isolate=436793591 function='Closure: () => void from Function 'printHello': static.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an issue of the library, the minimun periodic Duration time is 1 minute, if you put it less than that, by default the library put into 1min.

[Android Alarm Manager Plus Periodic Function not working](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/323#issuecomment-869017173)

If you need to manage less, you have to use a method channel.

Also, there is much information: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068311/run-a-background-task-with-android-alarm-manager-in-flutter)